# How to use an array as an argument of a function to add its elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I want to use an array as the argument of a function to do some calculation with them, but I don't know how to make the elements of the array variables that the function can use. i am working on java.script .

I am starting programming so I try to make it as simple as possible with the basic concepts that I have

```
let numbers=[m1,m2]
 function sum( numbers){
       let result = m1+m2
      return (result);
 }

  console.log(numbers[2,4].reduce(sum))
```

Comment: `numbers.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)`

Comment: I think you are confusing yourself by having two variables both named numbers. Look at the documentation for reduce to see what arguments are passed to the callback function.

Comment: what do you want to do exactly? cuz you code is a bit confusing for no reason. If you just want to sum all elements inside array then just use `array.reduce()` like the 1st comment

Comment: Have you read [the documentation for `reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)? It should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the syntax for reduce: array.reduce(function(total, currentValue, currentIndex, arr), initialValue)

Here is an example of how you can use reduce to sum the elements of a javascript array:

```
let numbers = [12,23,34];

function getSum(total, num) {
return total + num;
}

console.log(numbers.reduce(getSum))
```

Reduce will recursively call the function you have created.  Num will represent an element of the array being passed in.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use a function for that, `reduce()` is enough for your needs.

`acc` is the accumulator, it will store the total value of your sum in each iteration.

`cur` is the current value, in this case on the first iteration your current value will be 2 and the next one will be 4.

```js
let numbers = [2, 4];
const res = numbers.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur);
console.log(res)
```